# How can I find out if my service will be called from the web or console?

Tags: symfony

I am looking to figure out the right way if my service is called from the web or the console/ command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the function php_sapi_name() and check for 'cli' to check if it invoked from cli.

```
php_sapi_name() == 'cli'
```

https://www.php.net/php_sapi_name